# is there a way to change dynamic the water mark text color when using ffmpeg depending on the background color when recording a vieo file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

This command in the command prompt window is working fine and recording the entire screen:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -i desktop -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

this command prompt add a water mark text in the middle of the screen in white color:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -i desktop -vf "drawtext=fontfile=path/to/arial.ttf:text='All rights reserved to ...':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

the problem is that the water mark text is in white and i can see it only when the background window color is black for example when i bring to the front the ffmpeg console window:

[image: water mark]

but when it's recording some window with white background, because the text is white it can't be seen.

I want to update the command prompt of the ffmpeg to make somehow dynamic so if the background window is black show the water mark text in white and then if I'm bringing up a window with background white change the water mark text automatic to black.

this is the command i tried for the dynamic effect but it didn't work i got errors and then i tried so many versions of the command line, but nothing helped or worked.

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -i desktop -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=text='Watermark Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=24,format=rgba [txt];[txt]split=2 [bw][wc];[bw]lut=r=val*2 [b];[wc]lut=r=val*0.5+0.5:g=val*0.5+0.5:b=val*0.5+0.5 [wc];[wc][b]alphamerge [wm];[wm][0:v]overlay=10:10[outv]" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -map "[outv]" out.mp4
```

and also tried this

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -i desktop -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=text='Watermark Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontfile=Arial.ttf:fontsize=24,format=rgba [txt];[txt]split=2 [bw][wm];[bw][1:v]split=3 [b][g][r];[b]geq=r=0:g=0.5:b=0 [b];[g]geq=r=0:g=0:b=0.5 [g];[r]geq=r=0.5:g=0:b=0 [r];[wm][b][g][r]merge=3,format=rgba [watermark];[0:v][watermark]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" -map "[watermark]" -map 0:a? -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -preset ultrafast out.mp4
```